# Missing cache context from local tabs

Tags: caching

As title suggest local tasks by default adds "route" cache context but my client somehow avoided it. All tabs on all pages looks the same.

I am struggling to recreate this issue and I suspect this is random case because it happened more than once in last 2-3 weeks. Before that everything was working fine for ages. I am using Drupal 10.2.2.

Any idea or lead how this happened would help, because I am running out of ideas. Thanks in advance.

[image]

These three cache contexts are there because is is configured as required cache contexts.

edit:
Cached tabs seems to be random, sometimes it is from user tabs, sometimes it is from from some other page.

Comment: This could happen by rendering only parts of the block and not the entire {{ content }}.

Comment: @4uk4 I checked but it seems this is not the case.